# Check if button is pressed in QGIS 3 module

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qt, pyqt5

There is a plugin I wrote for QGIS and I added some buttons there.
From main launch Python script I need to check is specific button is clicked and according to that do some stuff.

I saw a default condition in main script:

```
def run(self):
    if self.first_start == True:
        self.first_start = False
        self.dlg = frame_builderDialog()
    self.dlg.show()
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    if result:
        pass
        'or do something'
```

In this case I can catch event if I had an "OK\Cancel" button. But I have another simple buttons. I tried to catch them using something like

```
result_btn = self.dlg.pushButton.clicked
```

where `pushButton` is one of the buttons taken from script with dialog, but nothing were returned.

What should be done here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python you have "events" and "events handler". when an event occurs they usually (not always...) generate a **signal** that can be caught by the event handler.

for example :

```
curLayer.selectionChanged.connect(self.test)
```

the event is **selectionChanged** and the event handler is the function handling the signal received (in that case the handler should be a function (written by you) called test (or any other naming ofc).

your snippet :

```
result_btn = self.dlg.pushButton.clicked
```

Is meaningless (imho ...)

So ... in your case u should try an

```
self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.my_event_handler)
```

And write an **my_event_handler** function of course.

Answer (score 3):

You could connect the `pushButton` to a function so that when it is clicked, it will do something:

```
result_btn = self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.someFunction)
```

Answer (score 0):

The event handler function looks something like this:

```
def handlepushbutton(self,flag):
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage("clicked on a button", "DEBUG")
```

And in the run() method you set the handler to call the handlepushbutton() method:

```
self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.handlepushbutton)
```

pushButton is the name of the push button in QtDesigner. Subsequent buttons in the same dialogbox are named pushButton_2, pushButton_3, etc.